# Adding layers in the middle of the deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to add new layers to a complex CNN model in Keras, how can I add a new layers in the **middle** of the sequential deep learning model?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "in the middle". Do you mean adding an intermediate layer to an already trained model? That won't be possible. You'd probably need to redefine network architecture and train again.

Comment: @hssay  I am using VGG model and I want to add additional layers (e.g. batch normalization layers) to the network without redefine the network from scratch